# modifying page data after redirecting

Tags: php, authentication, post, redirect

I'm making a web page using php code, where the index.php code changes after the user successfully log in.
The user starts at index.php before loging in, gets directed to login.php then redirected back to index.php. The index.php have a completely different code after and before loging in. I want to know what is the correct approach to make to the page to modify it, because I'm trying if statements and they don't seem to work.

index page

```
<?php

   require_once "pdo.php";
   session_start();
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
        <head>
        <title>Index Page</title>
    </head>
     <body>
       <div class="container">
          <h2>Welcome to the Automobiles Database</h2>
          <?php
          if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
          echo '<p style="color:red">'.$_SESSION['error']."</p>\n";
          unset($_SESSION['error']);
          }
          if ( isset($_SESSION['success']) ) {
          echo '<p style="color:green">'.$_SESSION['success']."</p>\n";
          unset($_SESSION['success']);
          }
          if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['pass']))//this code should work if the 
                                                                //user is not loged in
          {
          echo '<p><a href="login.php">Please log in</a></p>' ;
          echo '<p>Attempt to <a href="add.php">add data</a> without logging in</p>' ;
          }
          if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass']))//this code should work if the user      
                                                             //is loged in
          {  
         if(isset($_POST['make']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['model']) &&                                                
         isset($_POST['mileage']))//this code should work if the user entered data
         {

          echo('<table border="1">'."\n");
          $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * autos");
          while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          echo "<tr><td>";
          echo(htmlentities($row['make']));
          echo("</td><td>");
          echo(htmlentities($row['model']));
          echo("</td><td>");
          echo(htmlentities($row['year']));
          echo("</td><td>");
          echo(htmlentities($row['mileage']));
          echo("</td><td>");
          echo('<a href="edit.php?user_id='.$row['user_id'].'">Edit</a> / ');
          echo('<a href="delete.php?user_id='.$row['user_id'].'">Delete</a>');
          echo("</td></tr>\n");
  }
}
         else if(!isset($_POST['make']) || !isset($_POST['year']) || !isset($_POST['model']) ||     
         !isset($_POST['mileage']))//this code should work if the user didn't enter data
         {
         echo "<p>no rows found</p>";

         }
    echo '<p><a href="add.php">Add New Entery</a></p>';
    echo '<p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>';
}
?>
```

login page

```php
<?php

   require_once "pdo.php";
   session_start();
   if ( isset($_POST['cancel'] ) ) {
        header("Location: login.php?name=".urlcode($_POST['email']));
       return;
    }

$salt = "XyZzy12*_";
$stored_hash = "1a52e17fa899cf40fb04cfc42e6352f1";  // Pw is php 123

$failure = false;  // If we have no POST data

// Check to see if we have some POST data, if we do process it
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {
    if ( strlen($_POST['email']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "User name and password are required";
        header("Location: login.php");
        return;
    }    
    else if (!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Email must have an at-sign (@)";
        header("Location: login.php");
        return;
    } 
     else {
        $check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);
        if ( $check == $stored_hash ) {
            error_log("Login success ".$_POST['email']);
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['email'];
            header("Location: index.php");
            return;
        } else {
            error_log("Login fail ".$_POST['email']." $check");
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Incorrect password";
            header("Location: login.php");
            return;
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
       href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
       integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" 
       crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" 
       href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

   <script
       src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
       integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
        integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Please Log In</h1>
   <?php
       if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
       echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION['error'])."</p>\n");
       unset($_SESSION['error']);
       }  
  ?>
    <form method="POST" action="login.php">
      User Name <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
      Password <input type="text" name="pass"><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Log In">
      <a href="index.php">Cancel</a></p>
    </form>
    <p>
    For a password hint, view source and find a password hint
    in the HTML comments.
    <!-- Hint: The password is the three character name of the
    programming language used in this class (all lower case)
    followed by 123. -->
    </p>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Life would be easier if you didn't try to do everything in the same script. There's not that many lines of code and it's already becoming a headache to read. Separate your auth routine from your views --- into separate files, and preferably into functions/classes to make them easy to include and use without side-effects. Keep your index.php minimal. `if(request_login()) { process_login() }` ... and later, `if(user_is_auth()) { echo get_view_user(); } else { echo get_view_guest(); }` -- for a very basic idea.

Answer (score -1):

You should make 3 pages instead.

In index ,check user is logged.
If logged, redirect to home page.
If not logged, call die() and redirect to login page.